# My post requests are resolved before $q.all is executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

In my scenario I have a this code:

```
save : function ( distinta ) {

    var configDistinta = { 
        params : {
            data: $filter('date')(distinta.data , "dd/MM/yyyy") ,
            tipologia: distinta.tipologia, 
            idProdotto: distinta.elencoIngredienti[0].prodotto.id, 
            lottoProdotto: distinta.lottoProdotto,
            quantitaProdotto : distinta.quantitaProdotto,
            corpiEstranei : distinta.corpiEstranei,
            tipoConformita : distinta.tipoConformita,
            siglaControllo: distinta.siglaControllo,
            azioneCorrettiva: distinta.azioneCorrettiva,
            firmaOperatore: distinta.firmaOperatore,
            firmaResponsabile: distinta.firmaResponsabile,
        note : distinta.note,
        visualizzaDettaglio:distinta.visualizzaDettaglio
        } 
    };

    var promises = [];
    var distinta_id = null;

    // chiamata post per inserimento distinta
    return $http.post(urlDistinte, "", configDistinta).then (function(response) {
        distinta_id = response.data.id;
        console.log (response);
        console.log ("INIZIO INSERIMENTO INGREDIENTI");
          //INSERIMENTO INGREDIENTI NELLA DISTINTA,

        for (var k in distinta.elencoIngredienti) {
          if (!distinta.elencoIngredienti[k].cancel == true) {

            var configDistintaIngrediente = {params: {
              distintaBaseGelato_id : 2,
              ingrediente_id : 1,
              quantitaIngrediente : 45.56,
              lottoIngrediente : distinta.elencoIngredienti[k].lottoIngrediente } 
            };

            var p = $http.post(urlDistinteIngredienti, "", configDistintaIngrediente)
            .success(function(data) {
              alert ("OK");
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert (
                "data: " + data + "\n" + 
                "status: " + status + "\n" + 
                "headers: " + headers + "\n" + 
                "config: " + config + "\n" 

                );

              console.log (config);
            });

            //promises.push (p);
          }
        }
        console.log( promises );
        console.log ("FINE INSERIMENTO INGREDIENTI");
        $q.all( promises ).then( function(data) {
                console.log ("AVVIO OPERAZIONI GESTIONE DISTINTA")
                for (var k in data ) {
                console.log(data[k]);
                };
                console.log ("FINE OPERAZIONI GESTIONE DISTINTA")
          return data;
        });
    });
  }
```

I see that my requests "post" are performed before arriving at `$q.all`.
How do I insert them into an array and then run them only `$q.all`?

Comment: Why do you want that? The main purpose of `q.all()` is not to pause all promises till other execute but to perform some actions only when all promises have been resolved (or rejected). It's totally OK if your `post` requests will start executing before calling `q.all()` in your code, it's a matter of what to do after all of them have finished, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I thought that was managing q.all also the start of the requests...thank you very much

Comment: "...only when all promises have been resolved (or rejected)..." - That's not quite true. $q.all returns a promise that is resolved only when all the promises in `promises` array are resolved. If any of the promises is rejected, the resulting promise will be rejected as well.

Comment: Please show us your console output, especially the one from `console.log( promises );`

Comment: thanks you all. I thought q.all also was the starting of the request. But it work fine in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Your `promises` array is empty, that's why `$q.all` is executed before your other requests.

In order to work, you need to fill in the `promises` array with your requests as following:

```
promises.push($http.post(urlDistinte, "", configDistinta).then (function(response) {...}));
promises.push($http.post(urlDistinteIngredienti, "", configDistintaIngrediente)...);
```

And then `$q.all` will execute after all requests return success.